# What is the effect of falling to your death in Metroid Prime 3?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

In *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption*, what happens when you fall to your death? I've done it many, many, many times and I just seem to pick up when I left off... I think I lose energy, but I'm not sure? Does it count as a continue? (Does the game even track the number of times I have continued after dying?) Does it depend on the difficulty level? Or is it just perfectly A-Ok to fall to your death, there's no effect on the game at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You take damage and "respawn" nearby. I think the damage might vary with difficulty, but **the damage is the only penalty.**

It worked the same way in the previous 2 Prime games.